# Adaboost and factor variables

Tags: categorical-data, boosting

My dataset contains both numerical and categorical features like education level, region etc (i use factor variable type for them). I think these variables are important for predicting the outcome of my experiment and training the final classifier. I was recently learning about Adaboost and I want to train boosting classifier on this data.

What I don't understand is how should I treat categorical data within the boosting algorithm. Most of R boosting package do not support factor variables as features (except for R's package gbm which supports up to 1024 levels). I think that the biggest issue here is how factor variables are coded, because most of the packages do not support automatic conversion, is that right?

What coding is used gbm package? Is it dummy coding?

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for Stackoverflow since it's more related to exact implementation rather than statistical background?